# How do I customize the path to the bundles in webpack?

Tags: webpack

We're building a project with webpack, and we're trying to customize the path used to load the bundles. In our environment, we have some ngnix configurations that have our application load in a subdirectory rather than the root.

It looks like the index.html file generated by webpack always looks to the root for the bundle files. The output is currently 'script src=main.bundle.js' but what we need is 'script src="/subdir/main.bundle.js"'.

Is there a setting in webpack that allows us to change the bundle path in index.html or does it always just assume all files are in the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify anywhere you want the bundle.js file to appear or even name it something else.  Wherever that specification is, the html should point to that location and that filename.

https://webpack.js.org/